# node js send post request with raw request body

Tags: node.js, post

```
var req ={
      "request": {
        "header": {
          "username": "name",
          "password": "password"
        },
        "body": {
        "shape":"round"    
    }
      }
    };

    request.post(
        {url:'posturl',

        body: JSON.stringify(req),
        headers: { "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"}
        },
        function (error, response, body) {        
            if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
                console.log(body)
            }
        }
    );
```

I want to send raw request body in req variable . It is working on postman but in node js i am not able to send the raw json as request body for post request .

Comment: What is the error? Could your `"content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"` be incorrect, since you're sending JSON? It should be `application/json`.

Comment: POST /HTTP/JSON/Prices/GetPriceSheet.aspx HTTP/1.1
Host: host.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cache-Control: no-cache

{ "request": { "header": { "username": "name", "password": "pw" }, "body": { "shape":"round" } } }        This is request preview that is working on postman . So i need x-www-form-urlencoded in header but also send raw json data. The error i am getting is wrong format from rest service .

Answer (score 15):

You are trying to send JSON (your `req` variable) but you are parsing it as a String (`JSON.stringify(req)`). Since your route is expecting JSON, it will probably fail and return an error. Try the request below:

```
request.post({
    url: 'posturl',
    body: req,
    json: true
}, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
        console.log(body)
    }
});
```

Instead of setting your headers, you can just add the option `json: true` if you are sending JSON.

Answer (score 2):

Change the `Content-Type` to `application/json`, since your body is in JSON format.

Comment: Tried that but "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" is also a requirement for headers.

Comment: Then you have to change your body to be in that format, not in JSON.

Comment: Yes i guess thats the problem I dont need json but data in query string according to content type . I will try to figure out format of x-www-form . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Adding the 'Content-Length' in the header for the string that is added in the body , will resolve this issue.
It worked for me.

headers:{"Cache-Control": "no-cache", "Content-Type":"application/json;charset=UTF-8",**'Content-Length': req.length**}